# Return one or more values from a list if they appear in a substring

Tags: python, list, function, substring

I have a list and a string:

```
lst = ['rock','paper','scissor','green apple', 'red apple']
```

I want to create a function that returns a string of items from the list if they appear as substrings in the text

So for example:

```
lst = ['rock','paper','scissor','green apple', 'red apple']
def my_func(string):
        .
        .
        .
    return print(new_string)

#------------

string1 = 'we like rock and green apples' 
string2 = 'i wrote on paper'
string3 = 'we played rock, paper, scissors, and had apples'

my_func(string1)
my_func(string2)
my_func(string3)

rock, green apples
paper 
rock, paper, scissor
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

```
lst = ['rock','paper','scissor','green apple', 'red apple']
def my_func(string):
    new_string = ''
    for i in lst:
        if i in string:
            new_string += i + ', '
    return print(new_string)

string1 = 'we like rock and green apples'
string2 = 'i wrote on paper'
string3 = 'we played rock, paper, scissors, and had apples'

my_func(string1)
my_func(string2)
my_func(string3)
```

Comment: thanks :) ill accept the answer as soon as it allows me to

Comment: Change to `new_string += ('' if new_string == '' else ', ') + i` to remove dangling commas